# Mouse disappears over gvim after installing NERDTree

Tags: cursor, gvim

I installed NERDTree and now the mouse disappears over gvim. Is there any .vimrc setting that would fix this?

[Launchpad Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+bug/616858)

[Same question @Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025762/cursor-disappears-in-vim-when-switching-windows-between-vertical-and-horizontal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `set nomousehide` did the trick.